# Convert BytesIO into File

Tags: python

I have a `BytesIO` object containing the data of an excel document. The library I want to use doesn't support `BytesIO` and expects a File object instead. How can I take my `BytesIO` object and convert it into a File object?

Comment: Possible XY problem. What are you actually trying to do. E.g., do you perhaps need something that supports a `fileno` property?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It would be helpful if you supplied the library you were using to work on excel files, but here's a buckshot of solutions, based on some assumptions I'm making:

- Based on the first paragraph in the [io module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#overview), it sounds like all the concrete classes- including BytesIO- are [file-like objects](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-file-object). Without knowing what code you've tried so far, I don't know if you have tried passing the BytesIO to the module you're using.
- On the off chance that doesn't work, you can simply convert BytesIO to a another io Writer/Reader/Wrapper by passing it to the constructor. Example:

.

```
import io

b = io.BytesIO(b"Hello World") ## Some random BytesIO Object
print(type(b))                 ## For sanity's sake
with open("test.xlsx") as f: ## Excel File
    print(type(f))           ## Open file is TextIOWrapper
    bw=io.TextIOWrapper(b)   ## Conversion to TextIOWrapper
    print(type(bw))          ## Just to confirm
```

- You may need to check which kind of Reader/Writer/Wrapper is expected by the module you're using to convert the BytesIO to the correct one
- I believe I have heard that (for memory reasons, due to extremely large excel files) excel modules do not load the entire file. If this ends up meaning that what you need is a physical file on the disk, then you can easily write the Excel file temporarily and just delete it when you're done. Example:

.

```
import io
import os

with open("test.xlsx",'rb') as f:
    g=io.BytesIO(f.read())   ## Getting an Excel File represented as a BytesIO Object
temporarylocation="testout.xlsx"
with open(temporarylocation,'wb') as out: ## Open temporary file as bytes
    out.write(g.read())                ## Read bytes into file

## Do stuff with module/file
os.remove(temporarylocation) ## Delete file when done
```

I'll hope that one of these points will solve your problem.

Comment: read() does not work on BytesIO. It sends garbage. User getbuffer().

Comment: Yeah, `read()` does not return what you want. Not sure if this answer was once correct but you do want to use `getbuffer()` now.

Answer (score 86):

```
# Create an example
from io import BytesIO
bytesio_object = BytesIO(b"Hello World!")

# Write the stuff
with open("output.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytesio_object.getbuffer())
```

Comment: `wb` ← attention to `b`, as it stands for [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 15):

```
pathlib.Path('file').write_bytes(io.BytesIO(b'data').getbuffer())
```

Comment: `getbuffer()` returns a Memoryview. `write()` expects bytes. Any suggestions to suppress the warning? Code works, but minor nuisance remains.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.10:

```
pathlib.Path('temp_file_name.tmp') \
    .write_bytes(io.BytesIO(b'data') \
        .getbuffer() \
            .tobytes())
```

Comment: Does it create an actual local file called  "temp_file_name.tmp'"?